# Jquery plugins like datable, but having ajax pagination and server side search as per needed

Tags: jquery, datatable, jquery-plugins

I am working with datatable, but lots of code should be written to have following features:

- Rendering per column (preferred not to write function for each column)
- Facility to show relational data like ({'name':'Suba Sah',role:{'id':1,'name':'Super Admin'}}). To show role.name
- Column based search functionality-(that might be date range, number range, text search and search should be on server-side),
- Load data per page not all data once.
- Control Table UI writing JSON if possible.

Is there any jQuery UI that above feature and like no code required to renderings and dynamic data loading for particular page.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know whether this plugin meets your expectations or not. But I feel the same as yours and developed one jQuery plugin namely `dynamic-table` and the link is - https://github.com/veshraj/dynamic-table

This may have some error. If you face any problem please let me know.

You just need to write html like-

```
 <table id="dynamicTable">
 </table>
```

and write column info

```
 columnInfo = {
    columns:
    [
                    {   name : 'name',
                        label:'Name',
                    },
                    ..
                    ..
            ],
            actionButtons : 
            [
                {
                    <a title = "Click to edit this record" href="::_links.self.href::"> <i class = "fa fa-eye"></i> View</a>
                },
                ..
            ]
        };
```

and initialize this as per documentation.